# Itext Sharp: adding a textbox to a correct position in the rotated PDF

Tags: pdf, textbox, rotation, itext

I would like to add a textbox to the rotated pdf (270 degrees). When I use a function of **GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNum)**, it returns a rectangle with an incorrect position. Thus, the added textbox is also in the incorrect position.
My problems are shown in the following figure:
[image]
Please suggest me some solutions to get the PDF position exactly. Thanks!

Comment: *GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNum), it returns a rectangle with an incorrect position* - The returned rectangle values are correct, merely not what you expect... Unfortunately you did not present the PDF itself, so one can only guess. One possibility is that the page has a crop box defined and Adobe Acrobat returns values relative to the crop box while the iText method as documented returns values relative to the media box. As mentioned, though, this is merely guessing as you have not provided the PDF in question.

Comment: @mkl: Thank for your reply. Actually, there is a crop box defined in my PDF  file but I don't know how to get values relative to the crop box via using Itext Sharp. I also refer to other topics related to my issue, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808795/adding-annotations-with-itextsharp-to-rotated-crop-box. However, until the moment, I haven't found any solutions for this issue. I appreciate all the support from you. Many thanks !

Comment: @mkl: I also check the another PDF file that doesn't define any crop box. As a result, the above issue doesn't occur. In addition, when I rotate my PDF from 270 degrees to 0 degree and retest then, the issue also doesn't occurs. So, my issue relates to the rotation angle and the crop box. Sorry because I can not show you my PDF  file.

Comment: I'll look into this later, maybe on Monday. Can you provide both the media box and the crop box values?

Answer (score 1):

**According to your comments** you identified that the issue occurs only for page which have a crop box differing from your media box. Thus, you should base your calculation on the crop box instead of your media box

`GetPageSizeWithRotation` essentially is implemented like this:

```
virtual public Rectangle GetPageSizeWithRotation(PdfDictionary page) {
    Rectangle rect = GetPageSize(page);
    int rotation = GetPageRotation(page);
    while (rotation > 0) {
        rect = rect.Rotate();
        rotation -= 90;
    }
    return rect;
}
```

`GetPageSize(page)` called from here essentially returns the media box.

Thus, you should have analog code based upon the crop box.

---

*EDIT* **According to your new results** it becomes clear that the problem is not coupled with the presence of a **CropBox** entry but more likely with the lower left corner of the box not being the origin of the coordinate system.

In this case the rotation of the box is executed differently by iText(Sharp) and Adobe Acrobat:

[image: iTextSharp GetPageSizeWithRotation versus Adobe Acrobat Mediabox]

- iText(Sharp) rotates the box dimensions and keeps the lower left offsets.
- Adobe Acrobat rotates the lower left offsets, too.

That cause for the difference: The PDF specification describes the **Rotate** entry like this:

> The number of degrees by which the page shall be rotated clockwise when displayed or printed.

I.e. the **Rotate** entry is not at all specified as something changing coordinate systems but merely as something changing the output orientation. Thus, those result are equally correct.

To emulate the Adobe Acrobat coordinate transition, therefore, one needs to program an explicit method. With those example result it should be easy to implement.

Comment: here is my result, thank for your support ! http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-L8Ul5q7DAIQ/Vb70yh2ofUI/AAAAAAAADhI/ysh8B9IL2VA/s1600/Media_Crop_Box.jpg

Comment: Concerning your result: `GetCropBox` and `GetPageSize` ignore the page **Rotate** entry; thus, they obviously return the same values all the time. `GetPageSizeWithRotation` and the Adobe Acrobat Mediabox output both take the **Rotate** entry into account. The different results are due to the specification of that value which does not clarify around which point the rotation shall take place.